# Where are the configuration files for the Wire messenger app saved?

Tags: configuration, transfer, instant-messaging

I like to move the configuration files of the [Wire messenger app](https://wire.com/) to a new install of Ubuntu. Where are they located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit searching, I found the config-files for Wire messenger app. They are orderly located in the folder:

```
/home/USER/.config/Wire
```

Comment: Are you sure it's isn't `/home/USER/.config/wire`?